# Why doesn't NLog produce any output when my layout starts with ${pad...}

Tags: nlog

Consider the following configuration file, in `NLog.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true">

  <!-- 
  See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file 
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
  <targets async="true">
    <target xsi:type="Trace" name="DebugView"
            rawWrite="true"
            layout="NEX|${pad:padding=-5:inner=${uppercase:${level}}}|${pad:padding=-16:inner=${callsite:className=true:fileName=false:includeSourcePath=false:methodName=false:includeNamespace=false}}|${message}" />
    <target xsi:type="File" name="LogFile"
            filename="${environment:variable=UserProfile}/logs/TA.Nexdome.Server-${filesystem-normalize:fSNormalize=true:inner=${shortdate}-${windows-identity}-${machinename}.log}"
            layout="${time}|${pad:padding=-5:inner=${uppercase:${level}}}|${pad:padding=-16:inner=${callsite:className=true:fileName=false:includeSourcePath=false:methodName=false:includeNamespace=false}}|${message}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="DebugView" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="LogFile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

For the target `name="DebugView"`, if I modify the layout definition to remove the literal text `NEX|` from the start, then I don't get any output at all.

If I put anything at all in front of the `${pad`, even just a single `|`, then I get output.

Could this be a bug in the layout logic?

Comment: please check the internal log: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging

Comment: @Julian I've actually tried that, but I can't seem to get the internal logger to produce any output either

Comment: Then please check https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: If you only log ${message}, is it then also an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in a demo case, see https://github.com/304NotModified/NLog-Demo-cases/tree/master/PadOutput

[image]

Comment: Interesting. It's definitely a problem for me. I'll try to narrow it down further in a minimal solution.